# Is there a notification handler for the keyboard size change during the password text entry?

Tags: ios, swift

I have set up the keyboard to toggle the screen when the keyboard shows up. But when the person tries to enter the password field, the keyboard changes size(Recommendations turn off). Due to this change, I am encountering a black bar at the bottom when the password field is active. So I need a workaround to change the screen height based on keyboard height.

Links to screenshots:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rPqIdHwtilGPdwrVxTQlDagLwogq3GzT/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kd7Ppi6ijr1xC15n3hKxdXBblUD0zWMI/view?usp=sharing

```
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
func keyboardToggle() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
}
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardSize.height)
        }
    }

}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a special override method for Password field, but you can fix the black color issue by setting the window color

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: This is a simple change that can solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle any other notification, It should work. Please make a small change in your keyboardWillShow method. Like this

```
  @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

   let info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary

   if let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size {. // I've changed 'keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey' to UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
    // if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 { I think its not required
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardSize.height)
       //}
}

}
```

Comment: Please also change view.frame.origin.y = screen height - keyboard height, something like that, instead of just decrementing every time.

Comment: Yes. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: If it works please vote and accept my answer. thanks.